# how to set a state within a promise inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state `this.state = { PathBased : [] , ...ect}` 
and a function containing a for loop ,after looping `this.state.data`  I want to add every returned element of the for loop to PathBased state , 
I can't find how to do it , could you please help 
by the way

> `console.log(this.state.data)` output is 5

```
async readFromLocal (){
        let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
        let path = [];
         let leng = this.state.data.length;
          if(leng > 0)
          {
         for( var j = 0 ; j < leng; j++)
         {
          path[j] = dirs.PictureDir+"/folder/"+this.state.data[j].title;

            const xhr = RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(path[j], 'base64')
            .then ((data) => {this.setState({PathBased:[...PathBased,data]})})
            .catch ((e) => {e.message});
       }

      }
    console.log(this.state.PathBased.length) // output = 0
    }
```

Comment: You aren't waiting for your promise to resolve before trying to log the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `Promise.all` and set the final result in the `PathBased` state. Also since setState is async you need to check the updated state in setState callback.

```
async readFromLocal (){
    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    let path = [];
    let promises = [];
    let leng = this.state.data.length;
    if(leng > 0) {
       for( let j = 0 ; j < leng; j++) {
          path[j] = dirs.PictureDir+"/folder/"+this.state.data[j].title;
          promises.push(RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(path[j], 'base64'))
       }
    }
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(data => this.setState({PathBased: data}, () => {console.log(this.state.PathBased)})
        )
        .catch(e => {console.log(e.message)});   
}
```